# Twitch channel to stream another channel

Tags: video-streaming, twitch.tv

I would like to stream another `Twitch` channel through my channel, but not sure how could I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is hosting. To host a channel you can either use a chat command in your chat (/host channelname) or you can go to that channel and click the host button on the bottom right. You can also manage your autohosts in twitch settings under your account (channels & videos)